# Plugins or text do NOT show up on custom wordpress template

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So I created a wordpress and on that wordpress I made a custom template.

The custom template shows up fine, But when I try to add plugins or text to my custom template via the wordpress dashboard nothing shows up. Its not adding it to the code or adding it to the page.

Below are some pic of what I mean.

This is the wordpress dashboard where I am adding at, As you can see my template is MainTest which I made myself and works perfect

[SS of the Wordpress Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqRdu.jpg)

[image]

Now this is the SS of the page, As you can see the words `test test test` are not showing up anywhere.

[This is the SS of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbpfE.jpg)

[image]

Here is the code for the MaintTest template page

```
    <?php
     /*
        Template Name: MainTest
    */
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content/themes/iribbon/newaddons/animate.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wp-content/themes/iribbon/newaddons/newstyle.css">
      <script type='text/javascript' src='rotate.js'></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Fancy/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Fancy/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

     </head>
     <body>

        <div class='container-fill'>
            <?php include 'wp-content/themes/iribbon/newaddons/header.php'; ?>
            <?php include 'wp-content/themes/iribbon/newaddons/footer.php'; ?>              
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".fancybox").fancybox();
            });
        </script>

      </body>
      </html>
```

And here is the CSS that controls it.  Yes I understand my CSS looks sloppy.

```
    #midbar {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 115px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1200px;
    z-index: 1111;
  }

  #midbar img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -160px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 250px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 2222;
    opacity:4.0;
  }


  .top {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 3333;  
    opacity: 0.9;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #navigation {
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    border-top-style: dotted;
    border-width: 2px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
  }

  #navigation ul li {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;


    margin:0 23px 0 0;


    z-index: 3333;
  }
  #navigation ul li a     {
    padding-left:15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
      padding-right:15px;
    color:#000000;
    display:block;
    font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
    font-size:18px;
  }

  #navi {
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    border-top-style: dotted;
    border-width: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 45px;
  }

  #navi ul li   {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 23px 0 0;
    z-index: 3333;
  }
  #navi ul li a    {
    padding-left:15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
      padding-right:15px;
    color:#000000;
    display:block;
    font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
    font-size:18px;
  }

  #slideshow{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #slideshow{
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 8s 16 ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 8s 16 ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 8s 16 ease-in-out;
    }
  @-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.3) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes cssAnimation {
  from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
  to { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.3) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
  }
  @-o-keyframes cssAnimation {
  from { -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
  to { -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.3) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
  }


  #imgholder {
    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #social  {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    top: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  #social .fb {
    position: relative;
    left: -5%;
  }

  #social .pin {
    position: relative;
    left: 0%;
  }

  #social .tweet{
    position: relative;
    left: 5%;
  }
  #foot {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin:0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #pics {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }

  #pics .ball {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    left: 140px;
    border: 2px solid #03acfb;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -4px #000000;
  }

  #pics .light {

    position: relative;
    left:165px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 2px solid #03acfb;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -4px #000000;
  }

  #pics .car {

    position: relative;
    left: 190px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 2px solid #03acfb;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -4px #000000;
  }

  #piccon {
    width: 1400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
    min-width: 800px;   

  }

  #rotating-item-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1940px;
    height: 347px;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: 8888;
    left: 0;
  }
  .rotating-item {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  body {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #mainabout img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #maintext {    
    width: 800px;
    min-width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    min-height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 175px;
    left: 40%;
    margin-right: -250px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  #mainabout {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    margin-left: -650px;
    top: 155px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    min-height: 600px;

  }
  .hidden {
      display: none;
  }

  .images {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;

  }
  .images img {    
    width: 30%;
    height: 60%;
  }
```

Please note, The css controls more then just this page thats why there is so much in it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please some code, for example of your wordpress theme's index.php or page.php, to your post. Without it it's just a wild guess on what went wrong.

Comment: Ok, doing that now. Sorry

Comment: @FrisovanDijk  I have added the MainTest php and html page also added the css for you to review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for no content showing up is because you are not including the loop in your html body. See the codex for further details: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Here is an example with the presentation separated from the logic which will allow you to have more control over the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

```
<body>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <!-- This will output the title of your page-->
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>

    <!-- the_content() function is required to output "test test test" -->
    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <!-- If there is an error, this 404 message will be displayed-->
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Oh no!</h1>
    </div>

    <p>No content is appearing for this page!</p>

<?php endif; ?>
</body>
```

Also, you should be calling your header and footer with the following functions:

**Header:** http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

**Footer:** http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: So how would that work with page elements, cause there not showing either.

Comment: @RoxyMiles what do you mean by page elements? Like images? Anything you put into your editor should be displayed in the page unless there is a problem with your css.

Comment: this is what I mean, None of these Elements are showing up   http://imgur.com/7W5hWZr

Comment: Oh - this is a custom theme. The original developer has extended the page functions - these are not universal. There is no way for anyone here to tell you how to add those in without seeing the necessary code.

Comment: Ohh, Ok. well thanks a lot. Other then the Elements Everything else is showing up

Comment: Maybe if you can track down the code I can help. This will be in the functions.php file most likely but it would probably help if you posted the original code for page.php instead. However, that is another question :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the loop to get the things that should be on the page. It's also reffered to as [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). Below the easiest example: show the content or say the page couldn't be found.

Insert that between your header and footer and you should be fine.

```
  <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_content();
    endwhile; else:
    print('<p>Sorry, this page couldn`t be found.</p>');
    endif;
  ?>
```

Comment: So how would that work with page elements, cause there not showing either.